# Can I change my heroes positions?

Tags: diablo-iii

After create a Hero, he come by last in the order in my heroes list.

How can I change his position, if I want him to come by the first one, for example?

Comment: Nope... Really hope they add it, though. I don't like my very first character, who I will always consider my main more than likely, buried at the bottom as I try other classes. It doesn't matter that much for me, but when people view my profile and heroes my better ones are all the way down the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be a feature yet. They added that late in WOW. They may add it later on in D3 as well. (at least I hope they do) The way they made it different, is they have that main character focus. So when you log in, you see the last one you played.

Comment: Also, after checking battle.net forums. People said no, it's not available right now.