# Can I sort characters by how recently they've been played?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there any option to sort the characters on my account fom Diablo III like in Diablo II (most recent char played to be the first in list)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change my heroes positions?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66373/can-i-change-my-heroes-positions)

Answer (score 1):

No.

A simple answer for a simple question.